Prove integral involving Bessel function and Gaussian function
In the course of a complicated calculation, I have to perform the following integrals:
$$Int_1=\int_0^{\infty} x e^{-\frac{x^2}{s^2}}I_0\left(\frac{cx}{s}\right)dx$$
$$Int_2=\int_0^{\infty} x e^{-\frac{x^2}{s^2}-bx}I_0\left(\frac{cx}{s}\right)dx.$$
Now, Mathematica gives me
$$Int_1=\frac{s^2}{2}e^{\frac{a^2}{4s^2}},$$
but cannot solve the second integral. However, I have no idea how to prove the result that Mathematica gives for the first one, and I feel like if I did, I might have an idea of how to solve the second one. Does anyone know how to prove the result of the first integral?
Thank you for any help!

Expand the Bessel function in a power series and integrate term by term. It's a pretty easy calculation.

You have a typo for the first integral : it should be  $$\frac{s^2}{2} e^{\frac{c^2}{4}} $$ that you also obtain using what @CameronWilliams suggested.

The second integral does not show a closed form : it would be a combination of  Kummer confluent hypergeometric functions

On the advice @Cameron Williams,for first one:
$$\int_0^{\infty } x \exp \left(-\frac{a x^2}{s^2}\right) I_0\left(\frac{c x}{s}\right) \, dx=\\\int_0^{\infty } x \exp \left(-\frac{a x^2}{s^2}\right) \sum _{m=0}^{\infty } \frac{2^{-2 m} \left(\frac{c x}{s}\right)^{2 m}}{m! \Gamma (1+m)} \, dx=\\\sum _{m=0}^{\infty } \int_0^{\infty } \frac{2^{-2 m} c^{2 m} e^{-\frac{a x^2}{s^2}} s^{-2 m} x^{1+2 m}}{m! \Gamma (1+m)}
   \, dx=\\\sum _{m=0}^{\infty } \frac{2^{-1-2 m} c^{2 m} m \left(\frac{a}{s^2}\right)^{-1-m} s^{-2 m} \Gamma (m)}{\Gamma (1+m)^2}=\\\sum _{m=0}^{\infty } \frac{2^{-1-2 m} a^{-1-m} c^{2 m} s^2}{\Gamma (1+m)}=\color{blue}{\\\frac{e^{\frac{c^2}{4 a}} s^2}{2 a}}$$
for second one:
$$\int_0^{\infty } x \exp \left(-\frac{a x^2}{s^2}-b x\right) I_0\left(\frac{c x}{s}\right) \, dx=\\\int_0^{\infty } x \exp \left(-\frac{a x^2}{s^2}\right) \left(\sum _{m=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-b x)^m}{m!}\right) I_0\left(\frac{c x}{s}\right) \, dx=\\\sum
   _{m=0}^{\infty } \int_0^{\infty } \frac{x \exp \left(-\frac{a x^2}{s^2}\right) (-b x)^m I_0\left(\frac{c x}{s}\right)}{m!} \, dx=\\\sum _{m=0}^{\infty } \frac{a^{-1-\frac{m}{2}} s^2 (-b s)^m \Gamma \left(1+\frac{m}{2}\right) \,
   _1F_1\left(1+\frac{m}{2};1;\frac{c^2}{4 a}\right)}{2 m!}=\\\sum _{m=0}^{\infty } \frac{a^{-1-\frac{m}{2}} s^2 (-b s)^m \Gamma \left(1+\frac{m}{2}\right) \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{4^{-n} \left(\frac{c^2}{a}\right)^n
   \left(1+\frac{m}{2}\right)_n}{n! (1)_n}}{2 m!}=\\\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \sum _{m=0}^{\infty } \frac{2^{-1-2 n} a^{-1-\frac{m}{2}} \left(\frac{c^2}{a}\right)^n s^2 (-b s)^m \Gamma \left(1+\frac{m}{2}+n\right)}{\Gamma (1+m) \Gamma (1+n)^2}=\color{blue}{\\\frac{s^2
   \sum _{m=0}^{\infty } \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{(1)_{\frac{m}{2}+n} \left(\left(\frac{c^2}{4 a}\right)^n \left(-\frac{b s}{\sqrt{a}}\right)^m\right)}{(1)_n (n! m!)}}{2 a}}$$
The last double series can be expressed by: Srivastava - Daoust  multivariable hypergeometric function see defintion  (1.3) on paper.
